# MS Access Error: Invalid Argument to Function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT Products.SKU,
    Buy_Orders_Details_Requested_But_Not_Sent_By_Customer.Customer,
    First(Buy_Orders_Details_Requested_But_Not_Sent_By_Customer.Requested_But_Not_Sent) AS     FirstOfRequested_But_Not_Sent
FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Buy_Orders_Details_Requested_But_Not_Sent_By_Customer
    ON Products.SKU = Buy_Orders_Details_Requested_But_Not_Sent_By_Customer.SKU
GROUP BY Products.SKU,
    Buy_Orders_Details_Requested_But_Not_Sent_By_Customer.Customer;
```

and I'm getting "Invalid argument to function".

When I run:

```
SELECT Products.SKU,
    Buy_Orders_Details_Requested_But_Not_Sent_By_Customer.Customer,
    First(Buy_Orders_Details_Requested_But_Not_Sent_By_Customer.Quantity_Ordered) AS     FirstOfQuantity_Ordered
FROM Products
LEFT JOIN Buy_Orders_Details_Requested_But_Not_Sent_By_Customer
    ON Products.SKU = Buy_Orders_Details_Requested_But_Not_Sent_By_Customer.SKU
GROUP BY Products.SKU,
    Buy_Orders_Details_Requested_But_Not_Sent_By_Customer.Customer;
```

it works without issue.  The only difference between the two queries is the field that's being aggregated--Quantity_Ordered or Requested_But_Not_Sent.  The underlying recordset "Buy_Orders_Details_Requested_But_Not_Sent_By_Customer" is itself a query, not a table.  Opening that query by itself works fine, without issue.  "Requested_But_Not_Sent" does not contain any NULLs.  When I dump the contents of the query Buy_Orders_Details_Requested_But_Not_Sent_By_Customer into a temporary table and join to that table instead of to the query, it works fine.

Of the query Buy_Orders_Details_Requested_But_Not_Sent_By_Customer, I'm finding that some fields work and some don't (as mentioned).  Why would this occur?  Why is it relevant whether the underlying recordset it a table or query?  And most importantly, how can I achieve the results I'm looking for without having to use a temporary table?  If more information is needed, please specify and I'll provide.

Thanks!

Comment: Of what data type is Requested_But_Not_Sent in the underlying recordset? When you dump the contents of the recordset into a temp table, what data type do you make Requested_But_Not_Sent?

Comment: Requested_But_Not_Sent subtracts 2 calculated fields, both of which are "Long"s.  When I try to aggregate those fields individually, I get the same error.  Those fields themselves are of the syntax CLng(Nz((SELECT SUM(x) FROM y), 0))  The "y" is a table, not a query, and "x" is a "long".

Comment: I didn't use SQL to add the data to a temp table, but rather copied to Excel and then pasted back to Access.  The newly created table/field was created as a Double.  (BTW, there are no fractional values anyway.)

Comment: And does the function FIRST accept both Doubles and Longs? If this is a built-in function for some RDMS other than SQL Server, I apologize for the question, but I'm not familiar with it and you don't specify your RDMS.

Comment: I tagged the question with MS-Access. "Quantity_Ordered" is a long, and that works, so apparently, "First" does work for Longs for my RDBMS.  And, it works for the temp table, so apparently it works for doubles as well.